# Android camera app gives error on back and home button

Tags: android, camera, android-homebutton

My Application gives error "Unfortunately PhotoComment has stopped" when I am pressing back or home button. But when I am reopening app from task manager it works.

this is my mainactivity.java

```
package com.cameratag;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private CameraSurfaceView cameraView;
    private ImageView imageResult;
    private ImageView imageResult2;
    private FrameLayout framenew;
    private TextView snapPhoto;
    private boolean takePicture = true;
    private Bitmap image = null;
    private String lastPreviewImgPath = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupcamera();
    }

    public void setupcamera(){
        cameraView = new CameraSurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
        imageResult = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        framenew = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        snapPhoto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        framenew.addView(imageResult);
        framenew.addView(cameraView);
    }

    public void captureHandler(View view){
        if(takePicture){
            cameraView.capture(jpegHandler);
        }
        else{
            takePicture = true;
            cameraView.preview();
            framenew.bringChildToFront(cameraView);
            imageResult.setImageBitmap(null);
            snapPhoto.setText("Capture");
        }
    }

    public void zoomMinusHandler(View view){
        cameraView.zoomMinus();
    }

    public void zoomPilusHandler(View view){
        cameraView.zoomPilus();
    }

    public Camera.PictureCallback jpegHandler = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            imageResult.setImageBitmap(image);
            imageResult2 = imageResult; 
            LayoutParams params = imageResult.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = framenew.getWidth();
            params.height = framenew.getHeight();
            imageResult2.setLayoutParams(params);
            //framenew.bringChildToFront(imageResult);
            //snapPhoto.setText("Take Picture");
            //takePicture = false;

            File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "NNCam");
              if (!directory.exists()) {
                if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
                  //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
                }
              }

              String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
              String filename = "/IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
              if(image!=null){
                  saveImage(directory.getPath(),filename,image);
                  cameraView.preview();
              }



        }
    };

    public void saveImage(String path, String imgname, Bitmap image){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path+imgname);

        BufferedOutputStream  stream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
        lastPreviewImgPath = path+imgname;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lastPreviewImgPath);
          ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lastPreview);
          myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            cameraView.release();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            cameraView.reconnect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
            cameraView.release();
    }
}
```

and this is surfaceview class

```
package com.cameratag;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private Context context;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera = null;
    public int zoomValue = 0;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();  
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();  
        Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(0);
        List<Camera.Size> sizes2 = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();  
        Camera.Size cs2 = sizes2.get(0);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(cs2.width, cs2.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(cs.width, cs.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int rrr = 0;
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        if(rotation==0)rrr=90;
        else if(rotation==1)rrr=0;
        else if(rotation==3)rrr=180;
        else rrr=270;
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(rrr);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera = null;
    }

    public void capture(Camera.PictureCallback jpegHandler){
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegHandler);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int rrr = 0;
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        if(rotation==0)rrr=90;
        else if(rotation==1)rrr=0;
        else if(rotation==3)rrr=180;
        else rrr=270;
        //camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(rrr);
        //camera.startPreview();

    }

    public void preview(){
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    public void reconnect(){
        try {
            camera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void zoomMinus() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(parameters.isZoomSupported()){
            if(zoomValue>0){
                zoomValue-=2;
                parameters.setZoom(zoomValue);

                if(parameters.isSmoothZoomSupported()){
                    camera.startSmoothZoom(zoomValue);
                }
                else{
                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void zoomPilus() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();  

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(parameters.isZoomSupported()){
            if(zoomValue<parameters.getMaxZoom()){
                zoomValue+=2;
                parameters.setZoom(zoomValue);

                if(parameters.isSmoothZoomSupported()){
                    camera.startSmoothZoom(zoomValue);
                }
                else{
                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }

}
```

Please help.

Comment: paste the logcat on crash.

Comment: do you have some error log???

Comment: i dont know where to read logs :(

Comment: log cat goto Window >  Show View > Log cat

Comment: I can't answer my question because I am new user. These are first 3 lines of error.

07-23 17:59:44.672: E/AndroidRuntime(5875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 17:59:44.672: E/AndroidRuntime(5875): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
07-23 17:59:44.672: E/AndroidRuntime(5875):  at android.hardware.Camera._stopPreview(Native Method)

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

  //        if (inPreview) {
 //         mCamera.stopPreview();
 //     }
 //     mCamera.release();
 //     mCamera = null;
 //     inPreview = false;
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    super.onPause();
    // mCamera.stopPreview();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, the trick is to also setup the camera inside of onResume().

The issue was that the app does not call onCreate() every time you go to an activity with the back button, sometimes it simply pauses the activity. onResume() is called whenever the activity returns to the foreground and is a more reliable place to set up the camera.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if( camera == null )
    {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your release code in try catch block

```
try{
  if (camera != null){
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my own. You only need to change surfaceDestroyed method to this.

```
@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and on onRestoreInstanceState to this.

```
@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            cameraView = null;
            setupcamera();
            //cameraView.reconnect();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work? I use an old device (level 2.3, and runs very slow). It takes 1-2 secs to take a picture. During the time of picture taking, I press the HOME button, it often (50% chances?) freezes in a preview state.